# Edge detection OCR Java Find numbers

Tags: java, image-processing, ocr, edge-detection

i ran a edge detection on this image. java

[image]

results:

[image]

is this a good way to identify the numbers? im trying to get the left side numbers and add them all up. what should i do? or what next step should i follow. i think i would have to run a ocr bt i think i need to get rid of the lines? by doing edge detection method is it possible?

Comment: I do it like this [OCR and character similarity](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22879053/2521214)