# To recognize a single character, do I need character recognition?

Tags: image-processing, image-recognition, pattern-recognition

Even if it is a **single** number or a letter we draw, to identify them would we call it as character recognition? Or would it be like image pattern matching, template matching or something else.

If we draw a simple shape like circle or square...etc, to recognize them what technique would be used?

Comment: There's a lots of methods. Depending on what do you need. For example, to find position of fixed pattern (which can't be scaled or rotated) you can make simple convolution. For lines matching you can use Hough transforms, the same is for circles (but you will need much more memory). Etc.

Comment: if you want to know which character it isi from an alphabet (does not need to be character at all) then it is OCR, if you want to know if image is some specific character then it is pattern detection/recognition/matching. All depends on the usage, variability of input and output. There are lots of metods each suited for different task and conditions. If you want something simple look here: [OCR and character similarity](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22879053/2521214)

Answer (score 0):

It is up to you how do you want to implement the recognition part, you can either use template matching or feature extraction, plus the classifier fit your data environment and the target.