# Java simple OCR algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, ocr

I've been working on a simple OCR project for a couple days. The app is supposed to extract a text from an image. The solution I've come up with is:
greyscaling, rotating, removing noise from the image and isolating every single character on the image. So I need some help with a simple algorithm that would let me recognise the character. I only need to recognise the letters A,B,C,D.

Comment: What sorts of ideas do you have about making the algorithm? Have you written anything to implement it so far?

Comment: see [OCR and character similarity](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22879053/2521214) `Pixel approach` is a simple deterministic approach I develop for a commercial project few years back. It does not use neural networks so it is free of their issues ... which makes it ideal for a rookie to start with

Answer (score 0):

The method i'd use would be to make a mask of each letter, scaling it to the rectangle you found when cutting the picture and "score" each letter, by comparing RGB for example.

Comment: Seems ok, but it will make it limited to recognising only some fonts.

Comment: Yeah sure, but i think by testing 2 or 3 fonts, you will cover 99% of all text. Also, different fonts looks like each other.

Comment: I would give it a try.