# Transition histogram for hand written character image recognition

Tags: python, image-processing, histogram, feature-detection

How to find transition histogram for following image (B is the image histogram shown on bottom and right side of it)? I tried to plot number of black color pixels in each scan line against opposing axis but its not look like the one i needed (in python).

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail on what a transition histogram is and the problem you are having?  It may be helpful if you posted some of your code so we could see where you are getting stuck. Is this with `numpy` or some other third party library?

Comment: looks like this [OCR and character similarity](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22879053/2521214) so I assume those graphs are pixel counts per row and column not histograms. That alone is not enough for OCR you need to add a few more especially for not filled characters. btw the right graph looks wrong (it should have a few bumps in it). If it is number of lines not pixles then it still should have few bumps ...