# Electronic Parts Cataloge EPC

Tags: vb.net, image, image-processing

I am new to vb.net and from pas few days i have been searching for some information. I was not able to find any proper guidance online so finally i thought that i should post here.

I want to develop a solution for EPC, electronic parts catalog. The problem i am facing is to click on the numeric numbers in an image to filter a data set.

I have tried searching online through several sources. I have tried to look into some image processing plugins as well but i was not able to find something robust and understandable as i have mentioned i am new.

Kindly can someone guide me towards the right direction.

Thanks,

Comment: I honestly don't understand your question... Could you provide an example of what you want to be achieved ?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to be able to include images which include say part numbers and read the part number from the image itself? Have you googled OCR (optical character recognition)?

Comment: In this link you can see one image. http://4x4abc.com/Mercedes-Benz.G-Class.manuals/partt.html. I want to make a win form application in which when i click on the numbers in the image i get the value? for example in the image there is number "1" when i click on 1 i get the value i.e. "1"

Comment: Then it seems to me you have two choices - OCR the contents of a portion of the image under the mouse, or manually create an image-map

Comment: that task includes many things like normalization of dynamic range and illumination, noise removal, etc ... but the core is to implement OCR. Most OCR are neural network based and need proper training to make them robust (for a specific task). If you want something simple and easily try this deterministic approach I use [OCR](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22879053/2521214) ... btw also for numbers on very poor quality images.