# Getting numbers from camera device

Tags: c#, algorithm, image-processing, ocr, emgucv

I would like to get the numbers from an image of a basketball scoreboard received from a camera device, by using OCR or any other algorithm. The input image is similiar to this:

[image]

How can I get the best result? Which algorithm should I use?

Answer (score 1):

1. **extract bright orange-red pixels only and binarize**

   so pixels near the Redish/Orange color above some threshold intensity are white the rest is black pixel.
2. **remove gaps between segments by morphologic operators**

   enlarge white pixels area few times to cover the gaps between dot segments so digits will become single object
3. **segmentate digits (for example by flood fill)**

   find first white pixel and flood fill recolor it to object 1 ID, then find next white pixel and recolor it to object 2 ID and so on until no more white pixels left. You can remember bbox of each object and filter out objects not matching digit properties: (aspect ratio, size, density)
4. **OCR each digit and reconstruct text based on digit position**

   see [OCR and character similarity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22879053/2521214)

If your camera is fixed you can manually hardcode the digits regions elliminating the need for bullet **#3**. Also you can use the black areas to determine digit areas as the border is black...