# Finding similarity between multiple images

Tags: image, image-processing

I have a black-and-white shape form, like the ones presented below, and wish to compare it and find the closest match in a database of similar images. I looked into Perceptual Hashing but that doesn't seem to work for low-resolution and mono-coloured images.

(1) [image: Shape form 1] (2) [image: Shape form 2]

What other methods are applicable in order to make such comparisons?

Comment: siamese networks are used for face or finger print verification and used in exactly the same way.

Comment: this http://stackoverflow.com/a/22879053/2521214 might help, also read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/27588077/2521214 for some ideas. are your images rotated or always in defined (the same) position/orientation. Are they always polygon like... (outline only) has the outline holes? add as much information as you can...