# How to align two sets of points (translation+rotation) when those sets contain noise?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, linear-algebra

Consider the following two sets of points. I would like to find the optimal 2D translation and rotation that aligns the largest number of points between dataset blue and dataset orange, where a point is considered aligned if the distance to its nearest neighbor in the other dataset is smaller than a threshold.

I understand that this is related to "Iterative Closest Point" algorithms, but in this case the situation is a bit harder because not all points from one dataset are in the other, and also because some points may turn out to be "false positives" (noise).

Is there an efficient way of doing this?

[image]

Comment: Have a look here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/186111/find-the-rotation-between-set-of-points

Comment: Thanks. This led me to this concept (RANSAC), which I think should be the approach that I should use: https://medium.com/@angel.manzur/got-outliers-ransac-them-f12b6b5f606e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I come across the same problem and found solution in [comaring the CCD stars observation figures](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43126580/13720066), the basic idea is to find the best match of the triangles of the two set of points.

I then use [`astroalign` package](https://github.com/toros-astro/astroalign) to calculate the transformation matrix, and align to all the points. Thank the Lord, it works pretty good.

[image]

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import astroalign as aa

def getTriangles(set_X, X_combs):
    """
    Inefficient way of obtaining the lengths of each triangle's side.
    Normalized so that the minimum length is 1.
    """
    triang = []
    for p0, p1, p2 in X_combs:
        d1 = np.sqrt((set_X[p0][0] - set_X[p1][0]) ** 2 +
                     (set_X[p0][1] - set_X[p1][1]) ** 2)
        d2 = np.sqrt((set_X[p0][0] - set_X[p2][0]) ** 2 +
                     (set_X[p0][1] - set_X[p2][1]) ** 2)
        d3 = np.sqrt((set_X[p1][0] - set_X[p2][0]) ** 2 +
                     (set_X[p1][1] - set_X[p2][1]) ** 2)
        d_min = min(d1, d2, d3)
        d_unsort = [d1 / d_min, d2 / d_min, d3 / d_min]
        triang.append(sorted(d_unsort))
    return triang

def sumTriangles(ref_triang, in_triang):
    """
    For each normalized triangle in ref, compare with each normalized triangle
    in B. find the differences between their sides, sum their absolute values,
    and select the two triangles with the smallest sum of absolute differences.
    """
    tr_sum, tr_idx = [], []
    for i, ref_tr in enumerate(ref_triang):
        for j, in_tr in enumerate(in_triang):
            # Absolute value of lengths differences.
            tr_diff = abs(np.array(ref_tr) - np.array(in_tr))
            # Sum the differences
            tr_sum.append(sum(tr_diff))
            tr_idx.append([i, j])

    # Index of the triangles in ref and in with the smallest sum of absolute
    # length differences.
    tr_idx_min = tr_idx[tr_sum.index(min(tr_sum))]
    ref_idx, in_idx = tr_idx_min[0], tr_idx_min[1]
    print("Smallest difference: {}".format(min(tr_sum)))
    return ref_idx, in_idx


set_ref = np.array([[2511.268821,44.864124],
 [2374.085032,201.922566], 
 [1619.282942,216.089335], 
 [1655.866502,221.127787], 
 [ 804.171659,2133.549517], ])

set_in = np.array([[1992.438563,63.727282], 
 [2285.793346,255.402548], 
 [1568.915358,  279.144544], 
 [1509.720134,  289.434629], 
 [1914.255205,  349.477788], 
 [2370.786382,  496.026836], 
 [ 482.702882,  508.685952], 
 [2089.691026,  523.18825 ], 
 [ 216.827439,  561.807396], 
 [ 614.874621, 2007.304727], 
 [1286.639124, 2155.264827], 
 [ 729.566116, 2190.982364]])

# All possible triangles.
ref_combs = list(itertools.combinations(range(len(set_ref)), 3))
in_combs = list(itertools.combinations(range(len(set_in)), 3))

# Obtain normalized triangles.
ref_triang, in_triang = getTriangles(set_ref, ref_combs), getTriangles(set_in, in_combs)

# Index of the ref and in triangles with the smallest difference.
ref_idx, in_idx = sumTriangles(ref_triang, in_triang)

# Indexes of points in ref and in of the best match triangles.
ref_idx_pts, in_idx_pts = ref_combs[ref_idx], in_combs[in_idx]
print ('triangle ref %s matches triangle in %s' % (ref_idx_pts, in_idx_pts))

print ("ref:", [set_ref[_] for _ in ref_idx_pts])
print ("input:", [set_in[_] for _ in in_idx_pts])

ref_pts = np.array([set_ref[_] for _ in ref_idx_pts])
in_pts = np.array([set_in[_] for _ in in_idx_pts])

transf, (in_list,ref_list) = aa.find_transform(in_pts, ref_pts)
transf_in = transf(set_in)
print(f'transformation matrix: {transf}')

plt.scatter(set_ref[:,0],set_ref[:,1], s=100,marker='.', c='r',label='Reference')
plt.scatter(set_in[:,0],set_in[:,1], s=100,marker='.', c='b',label='Input')
plt.scatter(transf_in[:,0],transf_in[:,1], s=100,marker='+', c='b',label='Input Aligned')
plt.plot(ref_pts[:,0],ref_pts[:,1], c='r')
plt.plot(in_pts[:,0],in_pts[:,1], c='b')
plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig( 'align_coordinates.png', format = 'png')
plt.show()
```