# Match in Python a LARGE set of (x, y) points to another set with outliers

Tags: python, performance, opencv, computer-vision, affinetransform

I have two large sets of (x, y) points and I want to associate in Python each point of one set with "the corresponding point" of the other.

The second set can also contain outliers, i.e. extra noise points, as you can see in this picture, where there are more green dots than red dots:

[image]

The association between the two sets of points is not a simple translation, as you can see in this image:

[image]

In these two links you can find the red dots and green dots (list of image coordinates with origin in top-left):

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fptkxEDYbIJ93r_OXJSstDHMfk67DDYo/view?usp=share_link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z_ghWIzUZv8sxfawOBoGG3fJz4h_z7Qv/view?usp=share_link

My problem is similar to these two:

[Match set of x,y points to another set that is scaled, rotated, translated, and with missing elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43126580/match-set-of-x-y-points-to-another-set-that-is-scaled-rotated-translated-and)

[How to align two sets of points (translation+rotation) when those sets contain noise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62238853/how-to-align-two-sets-of-points-translationrotation-when-those-sets-contain-n)

but I have a large set of points, so the solutions proposed here don't work for my case. My points have a certain structure in rows so it's difficult to compute a Roto-Scale-Translation function because the rows of points get confused with each other.

Comment: Are you sure this is an affine function? In the best affine transformation I can come up with, the green dots bend outward more than the red dots do. [img](https://i.imgur.com/5V5WukH.png) If something is a straight line before transformation, no affine function can make that not straight anymore. The affine matrix I used is `array([[ 9.69253613e-01, -2.98935821e-03], [-6.76362611e-03,  9.93787737e-01], [ 1.94357843e+02, -4.29782433e+01]])`, by the way.

Comment: These dots represent the centroids of the panels of a photovoltaic plant photographed by an aerial inspection one year apart from each other. 
So surely there is a correlation between the points of one set and the other, but I'm not sure it is an affine transformation.
Can you share the code you used to find the transform anyway?

Comment: On Stackoverflow it is more likely to get a good answer if you ask for one specific programming question rather than for a recomendation on how to solve a whole project. You can start by presenting what you already have tried, what output you would expect and where exactly you got stuck to achieve this. Please read [ask],

Comment: @exsurge-domine Here's the code I used to find that matrix. https://pastebin.com/YNJ31d0e I picked three green points on the corners, found the corresponding red point by eyeballing it, and put it into a least-squares fit.

Comment: Your second example can be matched in two ways, both ways have the same number of non-matched points. There is no way of knowing which match is intended. Thus, your problem is not uniquely solvable. Then, what meaning does the solution have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a method which can recover which points correspond to which other points fairly accurately, using two phases. The first phase corrects for affine transformation, and the second phase corrects for nonlinear distortion.

Note: I chose to match red points to green points, rather than the other way around.

### Assumptions

The method makes three assumptions:

1. It knows three or more green points and the matching red points.
2. The differences between the two are mostly linear.
3. The nonlinear portion of the difference is locally similar - i.e. if one point has the match offset by (-10, 10), the neighboring point will have a similar offset. This is controlled by `max_search_dist`.

### Code

Start by loading both datasets:

```py
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
from scipy.spatial import KDTree
from collections import Counter

with open('red_points.json', 'rb') as f:
    red_points = json.load(f)
red_points = pd.DataFrame(red_points, columns=list('xy'))
with open('green_points.json', 'rb') as f:
    green_points = json.load(f)
green_points = pd.DataFrame(green_points, columns=list('xy'))
```

I found it useful to have a function to visualize both datasets:

```py
def plot_two(green, red):
    if isinstance(red, np.ndarray):
        red = pd.DataFrame(red, columns=list('xy'))
    if isinstance(green, np.ndarray):
        green = pd.DataFrame(green, columns=list('xy'))
    both = pd.concat([green.assign(hue='green'), red.assign(hue='red')])
    ax = both.plot.scatter('x', 'y', c='hue', alpha=0.5, s=0.5)
    ax.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)
```

Next, pick three points in green, and provide their XY coordinates. Find the corresponding points in red, and provide their XY coordinates.

```py
green_sample = np.array([
    [5221, 12460],
    [2479, 2497],
    [6709, 6303],
])
red_sample = np.array([
    [5274, 12597],
    [2375, 2563],
    [6766, 6406],
])
```

Next, use those points to find an affine matrix. This affine matrix will cover rotation, translation, scaling and skewing. Since it has six unknowns, you need at least six constraints, or the equation is underdetermined. This is why we needed at least three points earlier.

```py
def add_implicit_ones(matrix):
    b = np.ones((matrix.shape[0], 1))
    return np.concatenate((matrix,b), axis=1)

def transform_points_affine(points, matrix):
    return add_implicit_ones(points) @ matrix

def fit_affine_matrix(red_sample, green_sample):
    red_sample = add_implicit_ones(red_sample)
    X, _, _, _ = np.linalg.lstsq(red_sample, green_sample, rcond=None)
    return X

X = fit_affine_matrix(red_sample, green_sample)
red_points_transformed = transform_points_affine(red_points.values, X)
```

Now we get to the nonlinear matching step. This is run after red's values are transformed to match green's values. Here's the algorithm:

1. Start at a red point which has no nonlinear component. One near one of the `green_sample` points is a good choice for this - the affine step will prioritize getting those points right. Search around this point in a radius for the corresponding green point. Record the difference between the red point and the corresponding green point as "drift."
2. Look at all of the red neighbors of that red point. Add those to a list to process.
3. At one of those red neighbors, take the average drift of all neighboring red points. Add that drift to the red point, and search in a radius for a green point.
4. The difference between the red point and corresponding green point is the drift for this red point.
5. Add all this point's red neighbors to the list to process, and go back to step 3.

```py
def find_nn_graph(red_points_np):
    nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=8, algorithm='ball_tree').fit(red_points_np)
    _, indicies = nbrs.kneighbors(red_points_np)
    return indicies

def point_search(red_points_np, green_points_np, starting_point, max_search_radius):
    starting_point_idx = (((red_points_np - starting_point)**2).mean(axis=1)).argmin()
    green_tree = KDTree(green_points_np)
    dirty = Counter()
    visited = set()
    indicies = find_nn_graph(red_points_np)
    # Mark starting point as dirty
    dirty[starting_point_idx] += 1

    match = {}

    drift = np.zeros(red_points_np.shape)
    # NaN = unknown drift
    drift[:] = np.nan
    while len(dirty) > 0:
        point_idx, num_neighbors = dirty.most_common(1)[0]
        neighbors = indicies[point_idx]
        if point_idx != starting_point_idx:
            neighbor_drift_all = drift[neighbors]
            if np.isnan(neighbor_drift_all).all():
                # All neighbors have no drift
                # Unmark as dirty and come back to this one
                del dirty[point_idx]
                continue
            neighbor_drift = np.nanmean(neighbor_drift_all, axis=0)
            assert not np.isnan(neighbor_drift).any(), "No neighbor drift found"
        else:
            neighbor_drift = np.array([0, 0])
        # Find the point in the green set
        red_point = red_points_np[point_idx]
        green_points_idx = green_tree.query_ball_point(red_point + neighbor_drift, r=max_search_radius)

        assert len(green_points_idx) != 0, f"No green point found near {red_point}"
        assert len(green_points_idx) == 1, f"Too many green points found near {red_point}"
        green_point = green_points_np[green_points_idx[0]]
        real_drift = green_point - red_point
        match[point_idx] = green_points_idx[0]

        # Save drift
        drift[point_idx] = real_drift
        # Mark unvisited neighbors as dirty
        if point_idx not in visited:
            neighbors = indicies[point_idx, 1:]
            neighbors = [n for n in neighbors if n not in visited]
            dirty.update(neighbors)
        # Remove this point from dirty
        del dirty[point_idx]
        # Mark this point as visited
        visited.add(point_idx)
    # Check that there are no duplicates
    assert len(set(match.values())) == len(match)
    # Check that every point in red_points_np was matched
    assert len(match) == red_points_np.shape[0]
    return match, drift


# This point is assumed to have a drift of zero
# Pick one of the points which was used for the linear correction
starting_point = green_sample[0]
# Maximum distance that a point can be found from where it is expected
max_search_radius = 10
green_points_np = green_points.values
match, drift = point_search(red_points_transformed, green_points_np, starting_point, max_search_radius)
```

Next, here's a tool which you can use to audit the quality of the match. This is showing the first thousand matches. Underneath that is a quiver plot, where the arrow points from the red point in the direction of the matching green point. (Note: arrows are not to scale.)

```
red_idx, green_idx = zip(*match.items())
def show_match_subset(start_idx, length):
    end_idx = start_idx + length
    plot_two(green_points_np[np.array(green_idx)][start_idx:end_idx], red_points_np[np.array(red_idx)][start_idx:end_idx])
    plt.show()
    red_xy = red_points_np[np.array(red_idx)][start_idx:end_idx]
    red_drift_direction = drift[np.array(red_idx)][start_idx:end_idx]
    plt.quiver(red_xy[:, 0], red_xy[:, 1], red_drift_direction[:, 0], red_drift_direction[:, 1])
    
show_subset(0, 1000)
```

Plots:

[image: plot of red points and matching green]
[image: direction of match, from red point]

### Match

Here's a copy of the match I found. It's in JSON format, where the keys represent indexes of points in the red point file, and the values represent indexes of points in the green point file. https://pastebin.com/SBezpstu

Comment: Thank you. I think what you used is the right approach. For this plant it worked well, I will try it on other sets of points. Now I need to take one more step, which is to dispense with the initial three manual points , to make the process fully automatic.