# How to make gene_expression matrix from segmented image and XY cordinates of identified genes in spatial transcriptomics data?

Tags: python, pandas, opencv, image-processing

I am new to image analysis using python and am stuck with the following problem.

I have segmented images like the following: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eh2in.png)

Using cv2.connectedcomponentswithstats I extracted the stats of the objects using the following code:

`nb_components, output, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(thresh_image, connectivity=4)`

I have another table with xy coordinates and intensity values identifying point objects on the image from different channels. The table looks like the following:

| Spot | x | y | target_id | intensity | quality | target_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 111.0 | 49.0 | 1 | 422.68780 | 0.519918 | Act1 |
| 1 | 50.0 | 132.0 | 2 | 532.04517 | 1.630690 | Tub2 |
| 2 | 427.0 | 141.0 | 3 | 512.33620 | 1.317758 | Ser2 |
| 3 | 380.0 | 171.0 | 4 | 377.43110 | 0.911759 | Pol2 |
| 4 | 134.0 | 190.0 | 1 | 480.68900 | 0.884888 | Act1 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

As output I need a sparse expression matrix which basically locates each of the spots in the table to the segmented objects like the following(The table is only representative and not accurate):

| Gene | Cell1 | Cell2 | Cell3 | Cell4 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Act1 | NAN | NAN | 422.68780 | 480.68900 | ... |
| Tub2 | 532.04517 | NAN | NAN | NAN | ... |
| Pol2 | NAN | 377.43110 | NAN | NAN | ... |
| Ser2 | NAN | 377.43110 | NAN | NAN | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Any help/guidance will be very helpful.

Comment: Look into this for inspiration: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43126580/match-set-of-x-y-points-to-another-set-that-is-scaled-rotated-translated-and

Answer (score 0):

I'm not as familiar with the cv2 package but if I am reading your question correctly, I think that you can do this with skimage.measure (//scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html).

Assuming that your spot coordinates are in a pandas data frame called df_spots, I think something along the lines of:

```
from skimage.measure import label, regionprops_table
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#make a labeled image from the binary segmented image. Each individual object
#in the output image will have a unique label
labeled_img = label(thresh_image) # labeled image from segmented image
rp_table = regionprops_table(labeled_img, properties=['area', 'centroid']) # you can get whatever other stats for the segmented image that you may be interested in.

# from there you can iterate over the spot coordinates and determine the corresponding labeled object

# make arrays from the spot coordinates
xcoords = np.array(df_spots.x).astype('int') # need to change from float to int
ycorods = np.array(df_spots.y).astype('int')

# iterate over the spots and determine which labeled object they are located in
labeled_obj_lst = [] # list to hold associated segmented object index for each spot
for spot_iter in range(len(xcoords)):
    x = xcoords[spot_iter]
    y = ycoords[spot_iter]
    labeled_obj_lst.append(labeled_img[y, x])

# add the cell_idx parameter to df_spots
df_spots.loc[:, 'labeled_obj'] = labeled_obj_lst
```

From there it is a bit of data clean up to get to the sparse matrix that you are after but I think that you can hopefully get the data that you are after with this.