# Two path equality

Tags: geolocation, computer-science, computational-geometry

In my database I have these records:

```
path :[ { location : "some gps coords" , time : "some time"}, etc ]
```

Each "path"-record represents any real path.

How can I check any two paths on equality?

Thanks!

Comment: GPS is not precise so you need to mind that,... convert paths to polylines and [compare](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22166032/2521214) or compute the average distance of points of path1 to polyline of path 2 Then compute the same in reverse (points of path2 ...) If booth less then treshold (GPS accuracy) then paths  are the same (not counting inside loops ...)