# How does conversion of a raster image to a vector image work, and could it be used in image processing

Tags: image, image-processing, raster, vector-graphics

I am working on an image processing application, that uses pixel data to recognise digits in an image. I am thinking of an alternate approach wherein I convert the raster image to vector and then use the vector image. I am not familiar with vector graphics at all, and hence new to this, but just wondering the possibilities. Does anyone have any advice on this topic, or could direct me to some resources with similar approach ?

Also, could anybody tell me how does the conversion of a raster image to a vector image work, or provide me with related links ?

Comment: Resource requests are not on topic on Stack Overflow. Some Googling will help you get started. E.g. `(Name of your favourite programming language) raster to vector image conversion`.

Comment: Wikipedia has an overview https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_tracing

Comment: I got the impression that you just need to find/decode digits from image in that case much much easier is to 1. segmentate the image 2. apply [raster OCR](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22879053/2521214) on found objects (with size and aspect ratio near the expected font size) . If you want to vectorise then: 1. you need to detect edges (FIR filter) 2. extract edge pixels to a list 3. apply connected components analysis 4. join/merge/replace pixels by vector entities like lines,curves). 5. segmentate  the result. 6. apply  [vector OCR](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22166032/2521214)

Comment: As you can see the vectorise version is much more complicated and there are **many** things there that can go wrong. Some of them are handled by special algorithms like Hough transforms for Lines extraction etc ...But if you do not know the vector gfx and math  stuff I strongly recommend to avoid this approach because for beginners it is too much at start...