# How to compare two curves (array of points)

Tags: java, algorithm, compare, scilab, curves

I have problem to find method to compare two trajectories (curves).
The first original contains points (x,y).
The second one can be offset, smaller or larger scale, and with rotation - also array with points (x,y)

My first method that i did is to find smallest distance between two points and repeat this process in every iteration, sum of it and divide by number of points - then my result tell me value the average error per point:
http://www.mathopenref.com/coorddist.html

And also i find this method:
https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.0.0/en_US/fminsearch.html

But i cant figure out how to use it.
I would like compare both trajectories but my results have to include rotation, or at least offset for beginning.

My current result is calculate error per point (distance)

1. get coordinate (x,y) second trajectory.
2. in loop i try to find min_distance between (x,y) from 1. and point from original trajectory.
3. add smallest_distance what i found in 2 step.
4. divide sum of smallest distance by number of points from second trajectory.

My result describe average error(distance) per points if we compare with original trajectory.

But i can not figure how to handle if trajectory is rotated, scaled or is shifted.

Please look at my example trajectories:

1. http://pokazywarka.pl/trajectory/
2. http://pokazywarka.pl/trajectory2/

Comment: You should tag it with `[algorithm]` if you want something generic, or you should specify programming language you are trying to implement this, and provide your current results.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I'm writing in free software like scilab, or octave.

Answer (score 3):

So you need to compare shape of 2 curves invariant on rotation,translation and scale.

**Solution**

Let assume 2 sinwaves for testing. Both rotated and scaled but with the same aspect ratio and one with added noise. I generated them in C++ like this:

```cpp
struct _pnt2D
    {
    double x,y;
    // inline
    _pnt2D()    {}
    _pnt2D(_pnt2D& a)   { *this=a; }
    ~_pnt2D()   {}
    _pnt2D* operator = (const _pnt2D *a) { *this=*a; return this; }
    //_pnt2D* operator = (const _pnt2D &a) { ...copy... return this; }
    };
List<_pnt2D> curve0,curve1;         // curves points
_pnt2D p0,u0,v0,p1,u1,v1;           // curves OBBs

const double deg=M_PI/180.0;
const double rad=180.0/M_PI;
void rotate2D(double alfa,double x0,double y0,double &x,double &y)
    {
    double   a=x-x0,b=y-y0,c,s;
    c=cos(alfa);
    s=sin(alfa);
    x=x0+a*c-b*s;
    y=y0+a*s+b*c;
    }

// this code is the init stuff:
int i;
double x,y,a;
_pnt2D p,*pp;
Randomize();
for (x=0;x<2.0*M_PI;x+=0.01)
    {
    y=sin(x);

    p.x= 50.0+(100.0*x);
    p.y=180.0-( 50.0*y);
    rotate2D(+15.0*deg,200,180,p.x,p.y);
    curve0.add(p);

    p.x=150.0+( 50.0*x);
    p.y=200.0-( 25.0*y)+5.0*Random();
    rotate2D(-25.0*deg,250,100,p.x,p.y);
    curve1.add(p);
    }
```

1. **OBB oriented bounding box**

   compute [OBB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42997918/2521214) which will find the rotation angle and position of both curves so rotate one of them so they start at the same position and has the same orientation.

   If the OBB sizes are too different then the curves are different.

   For above example it yealds this result:

   [image: OBB]

   Each OBB is defined by start point `P` and basis vectors `U,V` where `|U|>=|V|` and z coordinate of `U x V` is positive. That will ensure the same winding for all OBBs. It can be done in `OBBox_compute` by adding this to the end:

   ```
   // |U|>=|V|
   if ((u.x*u.x)+(u.y*u.y)<(v.x*v.x)+(v.y*v.y)) { _pnt2D p; p=u; u=v; v=p; }
   // (U x V).z > 0
   if ((u.x*v.y)-(u.y*v.x)<0.0)
       {
       p0.x+=v.x;
       p0.y+=v.y;
       v.x=-v.x;
       v.y=-v.y;
       }
   ```

   So `curve0` has `p0,u0,v0` and `curve1` has `p1,u1,v1`.

   Now we want to rescale,translate and rotate `curve1` to match `curve0` It can be done like this:

   ```cpp
   // compute OBB
   OBBox_compute(p0,u0,v0,curve0.dat,curve0.num);
   OBBox_compute(p1,u1,v1,curve1.dat,curve1.num);
   // difference angle = - acos((U0.U1)/(|U0|.|U1|))
   a=-acos(((u0.x*u1.x)+(u0.y*u1.y))/(sqrt((u0.x*u0.x)+(u0.y*u0.y))*sqrt((u1.x*u1.x)+(u1.y*u1.y))));
   // rotate curve1
   for (pp=curve1.dat,i=0;i<curve1.num;i++,pp++)
    rotate2D(a,p1.x,p1.y,pp->x,pp->y);
   // rotate OBB1
   rotate2D(a,0.0,0.0,u1.x,u1.y);
   rotate2D(a,0.0,0.0,v1.x,v1.y);
   // translation difference = P0-P1
   x=p0.x-p1.x;
   y=p0.y-p1.y;
   // translate curve1
   for (pp=curve1.dat,i=0;i<curve1.num;i++,pp++)
       {
       pp->x+=x;
       pp->y+=y;
       }
   // translate OBB1
   p1.x+=x;
   p1.y+=y;
   // scale difference = |P0|/|P1|
   x=sqrt((u0.x*u0.x)+(u0.y*u0.y))/sqrt((u1.x*u1.x)+(u1.y*u1.y));
   // scale curve1
   for (pp=curve1.dat,i=0;i<curve1.num;i++,pp++)
       {
       pp->x=((pp->x-p0.x)*x)+p0.x;
       pp->y=((pp->y-p0.y)*x)+p0.y;
       }
   // scale OBB1
   u1.x*=x;
   u1.y*=x;
   v1.x*=x;
   v1.y*=x;
   ```

   You can use [Understanding 4x4 homogenous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214) to do all this in one step. Here the result:

   [image: match OBB]
2. **sampling**

   in case of non uniform or very different point density between curves or between any parts of it you should re-sample your curves to have common point density. You can use linear or polynomial interpolation for this. You also do not need to store the new sampling in memory but instead you could build function that returns point of each curve parametrized by arc-length from start.

   ```cpp
   point curve0(double distance);
   point curve1(double distance);
   ```
3. **comparison**

   Now you can substract the 2 curves and sum up the abs of the differences. Then divide it by the curve length and threshold the result.

   ```cpp
   for (double sum=0.0,l=0.0;d<=bigger_curve_length;l+=step)
    sum+=fabs(curve0(l)-curve1(l));
   sum/=bigger_curve_length;
   if (sum>threshold) curves are different
    else curves match
   ```

You should try this even with +180deg rotation as the orientation difference from **OBB** has only half of the true range.

Here few related QAs:

- [compare shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22166032/2521214)
- [How can i produce multi point linear interpolation?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30438865/2521214)

Comment: Ok but what i need if i would like comparison for two trajectory but second one is in 2x smaller. I would like consider this example if for example oroginal pattern was rectangle, what was draw but in smaller scale. So my calculation assume that trajectory is different but i want to consider them to be equal

Comment: @anna95 so even scale invariant .... simply rescale one of the curves so the OBB sizes will match. Or rescale booth to common longer side size ...

Comment: So maybe i should do normalisation for both trajectories from 0-1 spectrum value of (x,y)  and scale second one before i try to compate them ? What do you mean by sampling ? I should reproduce trajectory with the same density of x,y ? For example another coordinate for both trajectories should appear every 2 pixels ?

Comment: @anna95 yes that is **#1** all about but you must preserve aspect ratio of both curves. Do you have 2 sample curves (maching) for comparison ... visual example would be more comprehensable. And yes sampling is all about that booth the curves has the same uniform point density

Comment: 3. comparison is the same as mine solution. so if scale and rotated second trajectory i can redraw them from start of original trajectory and just calculate 3 step. I'm right ?

Comment: @anna95 more or less yes. Mine computes average distance between points of the curves coresponding to same arclength from start. So the threshold is in distance units with geometry meaning

Comment: Could you give me example how rescale one of trajectory  to the same size ? Thanks for help.

Comment: @anna95 do you have sample input data so I do it on the real thing ....  Do you know  Homogenuous transform matrices or you want simple algebra solution? Do you know vector math? How many dimensions is this for 2D/3D/4D/ND? `(x,y)` suggest 2D

Comment: this trajectory is in 2D. I have only set of points what user draw and try to compare them with my pattern paint. I prefer simpliest solution but if there is no exist try to implement it in my program.

Comment: i found this document:http://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/~parent.1/classes/581/Lectures/5.2DtransformsAhandout.pdf  There is information about scale Homogenuouous transform. I just wondering that maybe if i know how to calculate this rotation, scale etc. i could use minimizing method to calculate best paremter for trajectory. For example best parameters for trajectory to make them similar to ogirinal its : SHIFT: (x,y) = (0.22,0.25) , rotation: angle of 5 degrees, scale: 1 and result new trajectory.   Its called Affine Transformation which include all of  parameters.

Comment: Article: http://i3dea.asu.edu/data/docs_pubs/curve_matching_2d%20curves.pdf

Comment: @anna95 finished editing ... for my example the result of avg distance between curves is `~14` pixels.

Comment: it looks a little complex operations. For now i calculate center of gravity for both trajectory and translate them (each point) by vector defined byt gravity for centre. So i have both trajectories which GOC start from (0,0). Now i would like calculate angle between trajectories and scale..and after that compare objects.

Comment: @anna95 obtain the orientation is the problem. Either use my OBB or use PCA (principal component analysis). But if that is too complex for you then for some shapes is enough to either locate some distinct feature (like start/end point) or most distant point to center. In your case I would use start and end point orientation so if you got start`(x0,y0)`,end`(x1,y1)` and center`(xc,yc)` compute angle like `atan2(x0-xc,y0-yc)` and `atan2(x1-xc,y1-yc)` which gives you 2 possible orientations